# Qt.AltModifier and OS X

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The problem: this code does not print on Qt.AltModifier when running on laptop and OS X. It is consistent across both: PyQt and PySide. Is there a way to check if the QKeyEvent == ControlKey?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Custom(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        if event.key()==QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
            print 'QtCore.Qt.Key_A'


        if event.key()==QtCore.Qt.ALT:
            print 'QtCore.Qt.ALT'

        if event.key()==QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
            print 'AltModifier'


        if event.key()==QtCore.Qt.CTRL+QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
            print 'QtCore.Qt.CTRL+QtCore.Qt.Key_B'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Custom()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the `ALT` button has been pressed as a modifier you need to check `modifiers()`, i.e:

```
if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
        print 'ALT+A'
```